# How to write details of parameters in django api documentation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to write details of parameters that are passed to an api in Django. I installed coreapi and added url for docs page:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls
urlpatterns = [
     path('credit/', views.CreditAPI.as_view(), name='credit'),
     path(r'docs/', include_docs_urls(title='API Documentation'))
]
```

In views.py:

```
class CreditAPI(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreditSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        """
        This gets a post request with token and after authentication creates a credit for that user.
        """
        currency = request.data.get('currency', None)
        ####
```

So I have following document page:
[image]

My question is how can I add details of parameters in the form of a table in this page?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/coreapi/schemas/

Comment: @iklinac Thank you so much for your suggestion. I think it help me very well. Can you post a simple code for that?